# Android Virtual Device location error

Tags: android, virtual-device-manager

I'm having a problem with starting an AVD from Eclipse.
When I start the AVD that I just created, it gives me the following error:

[image]

I think that is because of the username in the path...

I tried to just copy the `.android` to `C:\` (=`C:\.android`) but the manager is just searching in the old path...

I tried to setup a environement variable like this:

Name: `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`
Value: `C:\Users\André Peixoto\.android\.android`

But it didn't solve the problem...

What should I try next?

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled the android sdk and now it doesn't show the weird characters:

[image]

But the path for the `AVD_2_3_3.ini` file still wrong. I think it should be: `C:\Users\André Peixoto\.android\avd\AVD_2_3_3.ini` instead of `C:\Users\André Peixoto\.android\.android\.android/avd/AVD_2_3_3.ini`

How should I change that?

Comment: did you put your android sdk under "C:\Users\André Peixoto\.android\.android" ??

Comment: No, the android sdk is under: `C:\androidSDK`.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084 check out

Comment: @rajpara, Thanks for the link. I tried the solution in `Comment 26` but the avd manager still searching the `config.ini` file in the same/older pathth, instead of the new one. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that using the solution presented on the `comment 26` from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084):

> No matter your configuration. If the message will be like this
>   "[2011-11-21 22:31:24 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\РЇСЂРѕСЃР»Р°РІ.android\avd\my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.avd/config.ini"
>
> (
>   "C:\Users\РЇСЂРѕСЃР»Р°РІ.android\avd\my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.avd"
>   - it's your AVD device configuration. )
>
> than :
>
> 1. copy direcoty "my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.avd" to some place where the path will not contain "РЇСЂРѕСЃР»Р°РІ" symbols (I in result had
>      the path like this
>      "d:\android\my_avd_devices\avd\my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.avd").
> 2. File "my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.ini" will contained in directory "C:\Users\РЇСЂРѕСЃР»Р°РІ.android\avd\". Open this file.
> 3. Change "path=C:\Users\РЇСЂРѕСЃР»Р°РІ.android\avd\my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.avd" to
>      "path=d:\android\my_avd_devices\avd\my_defult_android_2_3_3_avd.avd"
> 4. Save and close. Start your application again))).

But at the first time I tried this solution and it didn't work. So I uninstalled the android SDK and eclipse and reinstalled all over again. I also removed the environments variables for android_sdk that I had previously set and set a new one called `ANDROID_HOME` with value `C:\android-sdk`.
Now I'm able to run AVD.

I think this is not a ideal solution because each time I create an AVD, I need to do this process. But for now it solves my problem.

Hope this solution helps someone else.

**UPDATE - New Solution**

I was having some problems with the previous solution so I used a diferent approach:

I created a new account (Administrator) in my Windows which the username havn't accents.
I put my Eclipse folder inside `C:\` to have access from the new account.
Now, when I want to work with Android, I change to this new account.